# sys.exit() and pygame.quit() and os._exit(0) not working to close pygame display window

Tags: python, pygame

The sys.exit() and pygame.quit() normally work for me. I am currently experimenting with classes and class attributes. My guess is somehow the screen object isn't being shut down because of how it is created inside a class?

The print statement isn't printing for me - I checked if it is registering the quit event and it is.

Please help!

```
import pygame
import os, sys, random, math



class Game():
    active = True
    cell_size = 20
    max_cell_number = 30
    welcome = True
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size = (Game.cell_size*Game.max_cell_number, Game.cell_size*Game.max_cell_number))
        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    class Background():
        def __init__(self):
            image1 = pygame.image.load('/assets/image1.png').convert()
            image2 = pygame.image.load('/assets/image2.png').convert()
            image3 = pygame.image.load('/assets/image3.png').convert()
            image4 = pygame.image.load('/assets/image4.png').convert()
            image5 = pygame.image.load('/assets/image5.png').convert()
            self.images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]
        def generate_background(self):
            image_number = random.randint(0,4)
            image = self.images[image_number]
            return image

    class Cards():
        def __init__(self):
            pass
        def show(self, welcome):
            if welcome:
                self.WelcomeScreen()
            else:
                self.EndScreen()

    class WelcomeScreen():
        def __init__(self):
            image = self.Background()
            image = image.generate_background
            self.screen.blit(image,(0,0))
game = Game()

while True:
    if game.active:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                print("quit")
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)


    else:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        game.Cards.show(Game.welcome)


    game.clock.tick(120)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Its a typo `if event == pygame.QUIT:` -> `if event.type == pygame.QUIT:`

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the *type* of the event with `pygame.QUIT`, as the raw event will always just an instance of the `Event` class.

Corrected `while` loop:

```
while True:
    if game.active:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                print("quit")
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit(0)
    else:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        game.Cards.show(Game.welcome)

    game.clock.tick(120)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: So pygame.event.get() returns a dictionary of events and you can call on type, key using .type and .key